# Special decimal formatting

Tags: c#, formatting, decimal

Is there a string format that can be used on a decimal so that the following results are obtained?

```
123 => "123"
123.4 => "123.40"
123.45 => "123.45"
123.456 => "123.46"
```

In English, the number should always be displayed with exactly two decimals, except when it holds an integer value, when it should have no decimals (so no "123.00" displays are allowed).

Comment: What do you mean by "integer value"?  E.g. would you consider 123.001 to be an integer (display as "123") or not (display as "123.00")?

Comment: I meant integer in the mathematical sense, not related to any actual data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any such format, I'm afraid. You might need to use:

```
string text = (d == (int) d) ? ((int) d).ToString() : d.ToString("N2");
```

EDIT: The code above will only work when `d` is in the range between `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue`. Obviously you can do better than that using `long`, but if you want to cover the full range of `decimal` you'll need something a little more powerful.

Comment: This won't work for values outside the range Int32.MinValue to Int32.MaxValue.  When the OP says "integer value" I would assume he means in the mathematical sense, rather than the Int32 or Int64 type.

Comment: While true, the obvious use for this that I can see would be currency displays. In that case, it's quite possible that the OP knows his values will be in-range.

Comment: Added a derivative of Jon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not ideal, but a starting point. Simply format to 2 decimal places and replace any .00 with an empty string.

```
decimal a = 123;
decimal b = 123.4M;
decimal c = 123.456M;

Debug.Assert(a.ToString("0.00").Replace(".00", "") == "123");
Debug.Assert(b.ToString("0.00").Replace(".00", "") == "123.40");
Debug.Assert(c.ToString("0.00").Replace(".00", "") == "123.46");
```

Comment: Won't work if the current culture does not use period as decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "#.##" as your format string. So:

```
123.23.ToString("#.##") => 123.23
123.00.ToString("#.##") => 123
```

One caveat is that:

```
123.001.ToString("#.##") => 123
```

But whether or not that's acceptable is up to you.

Comment: I made the same mistake; this doesn't match the specification for `123.4`. It's such an easy mistake to make since it's such an odd format.

Comment: Indeed, we are using #.## right now but it was brought to our attention that the value 123.5 should actually be displayed as "123.50". It would have been nice if there was a format to do it rather than coding all this...

Answer (score 0):

You should use Math.Round method first and then use a toString() Conversion

```
    //123.456 => "123.46"
    myDecimal = Math.Round(myDecimal, 2);
```

The second parameter being the number of decimal places to round to
and then you do the following :

```
    myDecimal.ToString();
```

No real need for the N2 actually, this way you display numbers "as is" after rounding, ie, 124 if there is no decimals after point, or 123.46 after rounding 123.456

Comment: This will not work for 123.4 for example. The string will be "123.4" and I need "123.40"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public static string ToSpecialFormatString(this decimal val)

  if (val == Math.Floor(val))
  {
    return val.ToString("N0");
  }
  return val.ToString("N2");
}
```